# QtCreator убрать отображение абсолютного пути

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Написал обычное тестовое приложение для выбора `.png` файла из папок на компьютере.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QFileDialog"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString file1Name;

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    {
        file1Name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
             tr("Open PNG File 1"), "/home", tr("PNG Files (*.png)"));
        ui->File1Path->setText(file1Name);

    }
}
```

При выбере файла, показывает абсолютный путь до файла `"C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Capture.PNG"`

1. Хотелось бы узнать, как оставить только `Capture.PNG`
2. Хотелось бы узнать, как выбрать какую папку открыть и чтобы высветились все .png файлы находящиеся там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Хотелось бы узнать, как оставить только Capture.PNG

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#fileName

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const QString str  = "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Capture.PNG";
    qDebug() << QFileInfo(str).fileName();
    return 0;
}
```

> Хотелось бы узнать, как выбрать какую папку открыть и чтобы высветились все .png файлы находящиеся там.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryInfoList

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const QString folderPath = "D:/folderWithPng";
    QDir folderDir = QDir(folderPath);
    QFileInfoList pngList = folderDir.entryInfoList(QStringList("*.png"), QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

    for(const auto &item : pngList)
    {
        qDebug() << item.fileName();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: первый случай будет работать только на этот путь как я понимаю?

Comment: Для любого пути к файлу, будет оставлено только имя файла + расширение файла.

Comment: со вторым вариантов в GUI немного не могу разобраться

Comment: @Insider, может вам нужен [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName)?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb нет, getOpenFileName это только для одного файла

Comment: @Insider, [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames)?